# Assistance with datepicker and HTML table filter for PDO (PHP, mySQL)

Tags: php, html, pdo, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've been watching/reading tutorials, coding/recoding, etc., for several days now and still cannot get my feature to work properly. I have a web page comprised of an HTML table populated with data from a mySQL database using PHP. I have added a datepicker, script, and a form with user inputs, but have not been successful in getting the HTML table to filter based on those **from** and **to** dates from the datepicker. My struggle is with the PDO syntax: I just cannot find any tutorials that do this using **PDO**. Can someone help? I've tried AJAX and jquery datatables, but they end up breaking my table and I still cannot get the datepicker to return results. Image is shown below of what my page looks like.

[screenshot of page with styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsl1S.jpg)

```
<!-- This is my form -->
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
 <p class="search_input">
<input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="from_date" name="from_date" class="input-control" />
<input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="to_date" name="to_date" style="margin-left:10px"  class="input-control"  />             
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Search" >
</p>
</form>

<!-- This is my table including <thead>, <tbody> markup and php for populating the table from the database -->
<table class="user-table"> 
<thead>
     <th><a href="admin_view_general_ledger.php?sort=id">ID</a></th> 
     <th><a href="admin_view_general_ledger.php?sort=date">Date</th> 
     <th>Receipt #</th> 
     <th><a href="admin_view_general_ledger.php?sort=mem_no">Mbr #</th> 
     <th>First Name</th> 
     <th>Last Name</th> 
     <th>Description</th> 
     <th>Transaction Type</th> 
     <th>(-/+) Amount</th> 
     <th>Expense Type</th> 
     <th>Income type</th> 
     <th>Balance</th> 
     <th>Added By</th> 
     <th>Action</th>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM general_ledger a
LEFT JOIN balance b ON a.gen_led_id=b.bal_gen_led_id
LEFT JOIN receipts c ON a.gen_led_id=c.rec_gen_led_id
LEFT JOIN ref_gen_led_expense_type d ON 
a.gen_led_expense_type=d.ref_gen_led_expense_typ
LEFT JOIN ref_gen_led_transaction_type e ON 
a.gen_led_transaction_type=e.ref_gen_led_transaction_typ
LEFT JOIN ref_gen_led_income_type f ON 
a.gen_led_income_type=f.ref_gen_led_income_typ
LEFT JOIN member g ON a.gen_led_users_mem_no=g.mem_no
LEFT JOIN balance h ON a.gen_led_id=h.bal_gen_led_id
LEFT JOIN users i ON a.gen_led_add_by=i.user_mem_no';

<!-- This is some code I have to sort the table by column name with a page refresh -->
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'id')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY gen_led_id DESC";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'date')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY gen_led_trans_date";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'mem_no')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY mem_no";
}
}

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['gen_led_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['gen_led_trans_date'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['rec_receipt_no'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['mem_no'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['mem_fname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['mem_lname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['gen_led_description'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['ref_gen_led_transaction_desc'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['gen_led_amount'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['ref_gen_led_expense_desc'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['ref_gen_led_income_desc'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['bal_acct_balance'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['gen_led_add_by'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a class="btn" href="admin_user_receipt.php?rec_receipt_no='.$row['rec_receipt_no'].'">View Receipt</a></td>';
    echo ' ';
    echo '</tr>';
 }

Database::disconnect();
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- This is my script which does display the datepicker when the input boxes are clicked -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
buttonText: "Date Picker",
buttonImageOnly: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'  
});
$(function() {
$("#from_date").datepicker();
$("#to_date").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your query where you are telling the query to look for dates that are between your from date and your to date.

Put this code in for your php block:

```
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM general_ledger a
LEFT JOIN balance b ON a.gen_led_id=b.bal_gen_led_id
LEFT JOIN receipts c ON a.gen_led_id=c.rec_gen_led_id
LEFT JOIN ref_gen_led_expense_type d ON 
a.gen_led_expense_type=d.ref_gen_led_expense_typ
LEFT JOIN ref_gen_led_transaction_type e ON 
a.gen_led_transaction_type=e.ref_gen_led_transaction_typ
LEFT JOIN ref_gen_led_income_type f ON 
a.gen_led_income_type=f.ref_gen_led_income_typ
LEFT JOIN member g ON a.gen_led_users_mem_no=g.mem_no
LEFT JOIN balance h ON a.gen_led_id=h.bal_gen_led_id
LEFT JOIN users i ON a.gen_led_add_by=i.user_mem_no

WHERE a.gen_led_trans_date >= :from_date && 
a.gen_led_trans_date <= :to_date';

// This is some code I have to sort the table by column name with a page     refresh -->
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'id')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY gen_led_id DESC";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'date')
 {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY gen_led_trans_date";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'mem_no')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY mem_no";
}
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(":from_date", date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($_POST['from_date'])));
$stmt->bindParam(":to_date",     date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($_POST['to_date'])));

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['gen_led_id'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['gen_led_trans_date'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['rec_receipt_no'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['mem_no'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['mem_fname'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['mem_lname'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['gen_led_description'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['ref_gen_led_transaction_desc'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['gen_led_amount'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['ref_gen_led_expense_desc'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['ref_gen_led_income_desc'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['bal_acct_balance'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['gen_led_add_by'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td><a class="btn"     href="admin_user_receipt.php?rec_receipt_no='.$row['rec_receipt_no'].'">View    Receipt</a></td>';
  echo ' ';
  echo '</tr>';

 }

 Database::disconnect();
```

Some things for you to read on:
PDO Queries & prepared statements.
php date() function and it's formats.
php strtotime() function and use.

Your date picker is going to give you a date in the 
yy-mm-dd format.  You will need to make sure this date format matches your database time formats.  That should point you in the right direction.

You need to know what the date format is on your table.  I guessed at Y-m-d H:i:s. So I converted from yy-mm-dd.  These are not to dissimilar.  One is a javascript notation and the other is a PHP notation.

Comment: Correct, I removed that code because I really didn't know where to put it........I have the code to populate the table originally, but do I need an if statement to read the new query based on the filter being invoked? Not sure how to do this part. The correct column name to search is gen_led_trans_date. I know how to write the query and I know the format is an issue, but I cant get beyond the above issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Robin Richardson Kidder - Updated answer

Comment: Thank you, Joseph! This worked! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Robin Richardson Kidder Awesome, glad it worked for you!  Please mark as the accepted answer, thank you.

Comment: @Robin Richardson Kidder  I noticed an error in my code. In the bind statement for the to_date you need to change the 'Y-m-d 00:00:00' to 'Y-m-d 23:59:59'.  This will make sure when comparing the same date you get everything for the day.  Cheers!

Comment: Yes! I found that when I tested and have changed already. Works like a charm.....just one thing, if you don't mind? What if I wanted ALL of the data to initially display on the page in the table, and then invoked the datepicker for filtering only.....how do you recommend I do this? I attempted to do this by using jQuery and javascript onLoadSubmit with default dates set in the form values attributes, but my page goes crazy with either method. It works, but appears to run in a loop even though one is not there. Weird.

Comment: 1st query your table and display all your data.  Then you can use your datepicker to trigger just about anything you want it to do.  I suggest you read all of the functions available to you in the jquery datepicker.  You can use the onSelect or onClose methods and write your own js inside of those to display stuff how you want.  You could even incorporate some ajax for your queries and your page would never have to refresh.  Lots of tinkering to do there.  But it's definable possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check out datatables again, this would be really hard with your code. With datatables you can add it easily with a [rang date filter](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/row-based/range_dates)